# Getting extra data decode error requests package python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to the twitter decahose API via python requests package. I am able to establish a connection, however, I receive an error when I try to convert the object to a json using the .json function. I tried to use r.text or r.content but python crashed on my console (not sure if computer-power related or file related). Anyone have any insight into how I can transform the object into a valid JSON? Code below

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get(url, auth(username, pass))

r.json()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-52b7ec8d97cc> in <module>
----> 1 r.json()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    887                 try:
    888                     return complexjson.loads(
--> 889                         self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
    890                     )
    891                 except UnicodeDecodeError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2765)
```